# Grep pattern,which is repeated for the more than two time

Tags: regex, grep

I want to grep pattern which occur more than two times. So I use command grep "abc{2}" test_file.txt

But I do not get output.

`$ cat test_file.txt`

```
abc abc
def xyz mnp
def abc pqr abc abc
abcde pqr dlf abc
elf abc pqr
```

So output should be:-

```
abc abc
def abc pqr abc abc
abcde pqr dlf abc
```

So pls give me guidance for the same.

Comment: Do you like to get lines where anything is repeated two time, or `abc`?  What do you mean by `change number of repeat occurrence`?  Delete one or more `abc`?  Give better example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this grep command,

```
$ grep '.*abc.*abc.*' file
abc abc
def abc pqr abc abc
abcde pqr dlf abc
```

The below grep command would print only the lines which has exactly two `abc`,

```
$ grep -P '^(?:(?!abc).)*abc(?:(?!abc).)*abc(?:(?!abc).)*$' file
abc abc
abcde pqr dlf abc
```

Comment: But I want to do by regular expression command.Because it may be I have to change number of repeat occurrence.

Comment: No need to specify start/end to make this work. This is enough: `grep 'abc.*abc'`